# jQuery Validate error message fadeIn/Out

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-validate

I read lots of topic about that and i tried many things but It's strange I cannot make it work...
I would like when the validate error message displaying to display it with fadeIn effect. 
Then when the class has changed, mean that the form is valid, the error text should fadeOut..

[**FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/aecaadd5/13/)

**HTML** :

```
<form id="MyForm">
    <select id="MySelect" name="select">
        <option value="">Select a value</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
    </select>
    <button id="MyButton" type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

**jQuery** :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Form Validate 
    $('#MyForm').validate({
        invalidHandler: function(element, form, validator) { 
        $(element.form).find("label[for=" + element.id + "]").hide().fadeIn("slow"); 
      },
        ignore: [],
        rules: {
            select: {
                required: true
            }
        },
        messages: {
            select: {
                required: "Value required"
            }
        },
        errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
            if (element.is('select:hidden')) {
                error.insertAfter(element.next('.nice-select')).fadeIn('4000');
            } else {
                error.insertAfter(element);
            }
        }
    });

    $('#MySelect').on('change', function() {
        $(this).valid();
    })

    // Activate NiceSelect 
    $('#MySelect').niceSelect();
});
```

Any help would be appretiated.

Comment: Take [the answer from the very first search result](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjquery-validate%5D+fade+in) and modify [the jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2125dmb0/)

Answer (score 1):

I got it working on your fiddle with fading in by doing the following:

```
    errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
        if (element.is('select:hidden')) {
        error.fadeIn('99999').insertAfter(element.next('.nice-select'));
        } else {
            error.fadeIn('99999').insertAfter(element);
        }
    }
});
```

fadeOut should be the same idea. (I changed the fadeIn("") value just so I could see it working

Comment: Yes but the problem with I found was that the jQuery Form validation plugin simply removes the error text from the DOM right away when the `.valid()` method returns true. I do not think it is actually possible with the jQuery validate plugin for that reason i.e. you can fade it in, but not out

Comment: @Stacker, Thanks you it works, I updated the fiddle and some other little things (highlight/unhighlight)  **https://jsfiddle.net/aecaadd5/13/**

Comment: @Idra, Yes I can't make it work with the **fadeOut()**, I'm sure there is a way to make it but I don't know how, do you have some idea ??

Comment: @colapsnux I'm not sure, I looked into it, but from the validator own doc I could not find a way https://jqueryvalidation.org/documentation/ Like I said I do not think this can be done with the jQuery validator plug-in (but then again I am not 100% on that, because I have never used it)